# How can I split a string into two with POSIX sh?

Tags: string, shell, split, posix

I would like to split a string variable into two parts. The string have the form:

```
mingw32mingw32
linux64mingw32
mac64mingw64
```

I would like to get out:

```
mingw32 mingw32
linux64 mingw32
mac64   mingw64
```

I know about `cut`, but I think it is too simple for this. I can also do this manually (there are really only five or six variations) but I feel there is a better way. I'm just not too proficient in shell tools.

Note I want this to work in POSIX sh for maximum compatibility, so no GNU- or Bash-isms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use POSIX shell variable substitutions, but it gets a bit messy. To obtain the tail where a digit is followed by an alphabetic:

```
tail=${var#*[0-9][a-z]}
```

This obtains almost the correct tail, i.e. something like `ingw32`. To fix that, obtain the head by trimming one character plus the tail:

```
head=${var%?$tail}
```

Now the proper tail is the value with the head trimmed:

```
tail=${var#$head}
```

Comment: You, sir, are brilliant. This must be the lightest solution (and most portable) possible `:-)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using `sed`

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\)\([a-z]\)/\1\t\2/' file
```

or

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\+\)/\1\t/' file
```

If the width of the 2nd column is always 7

```
sed 's/\(.......\)$/\t\1/' file
```

or

```
sed 's/\(.\{7\}\)$/\t\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu awk:

```
gawk '{print gensub(/([0-9]+)/, "\\1 ", 1)}' file
mingw32 mingw32
linux64 mingw32
mac64 mingw64
```

OR you can use egrep:

```
egrep -o '[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+' file
mingw32
mingw32
linux64
mingw32
mac64
mingw64
```